# Xamarin.Forms NavigationBar property not hiding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

It was working for me but since I start using ***forms9patch*** Root page it stopped working.

I'm using content view to navigate to ContentPage like this:

```
 if (App.Current.MainPage is Forms9Patch.RootPage)
        await Forms9Patch.RootPage.Page.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new SalesScreen()));
```

and this is my initial class code which sets the Initial screen

```
 MainPage = Forms9Patch.RootPage.Create(new NavigationPage(new Dashboard()));
```

Please help :(

Comment: Have you tried passing directly the page to the method NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false); instead of using this and then pushing it to the Forms9Patch navigation?

Comment: Did you also try using `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` in xaml?

Comment: Yes I’ve tried both still doesn’t work

Comment: Is the BackButton also showing in the Navigation Bar?

Comment: Yes it is showing back button

Comment: You can also try adding`NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` to the previous              `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` in xaml

Comment: nope same issue

Comment: I am the author of Forms9Patch.  In the past year, a lot has changed with respect to how Forms9Patch interacts with Navigation.  Is this still an issue?